# Call Acceleo Generator From Java Class

Tags: java, eclipse, acceleo

I have to call an Acceleo generator from a Java Class I made. How I can do it?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the Java class automatically generated from templates with the `[comment @main/]` comment (to quickly get an example, use File > New > Acceleo Module File and tick "Create a main annotation" in the advanced options).

This automated class can be called from any other Java class you write by simply instantiating it and calling its 'initialize' and 'doGenerate' methods. Take a look at the generated `public static void main(String[] args)` method for a sample of its use.

Comment: if I do in that way I obtain Errors on the console:


org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/schemas/Standard/1' not found. (file:/home/cavallid/workspace/Acceleo_e_Java/src/Test1.uml, 90, 61)

Comment: Then you are in standalone. You need to register the metamodels and do the work Eclipse does otherwise by yourself. Take a look at http://eclipsemde.blogspot.com/2010/06/package-with-uri-not-found.html for an example on how to do it with UML (in your case, you probably need to do replace the "UMLPackage" but by your own "XYZPackage" (from the code generated for your metamodel).